# Boolean test HTML textbox input compared to array values

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox, boolean

I am trying to create a single textbox form on a webpage to boolean test the input submitted by the user. The input will be the website user's zip code. I want to make a predetermined array of zip codes that will test true.

If it is true (the zip code entered is included in the predetermined array), I want to display one bit of HTML, and if it tests false, I want to display another bit.

I've searched around and looked in some of my JavaScript books (I've just started learning) and haven't found an answer; could someone help me out with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML:

```
<label id="input-label" class="invalid">
    ZIP code: <input id="zipcode" />
    <div class="valid-message">
        Valid
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-message">
        Invalid
    </div>
</label>
```

### CSS:

```css
#input-label.valid .valid-message { display: block; }
#input-label.valid .invalid-message { display: none; }

#input-label.invalid .valid-message { display: none; }
#input-label.invalid .invalid-message { display: block; }
```

### Javascript

```
function isValidZip(z) {
    return ['12345','67890'].indexOf(z) != -1;
}

var label = document.getElementById('input-label');
var input = document.getElementById('zipcode');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    label.className = isValidZip(input.value) ? "valid" : "invalid";
}
```

Comment: Had to switch to onkeyup, but other than that, this worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this(might be a little off I'll double check then get back to you :)  ):

```
var zipArr = ['98671','97006'];//insert the zip/post codes here
var userInputEl = document.getElementById('userInput');//Get the element could use tag names or it would be better actually if you used jQuery but yeah
var elToShow = document.getElementById('elementToShowIfNotFound');
var otherElToShow = document.getElementById('idOfOtherelementToShow');
var userInput = userInputEl.value();//might be .text()
if(zipArr.indexOf(userInput) === -1){//-1 means it isn't found in the array
    zipArr.push(userInput);//pushes the new one onto the array        
    elToShow.style.display = 'block';//this changes the css display to block instead of it being hidden.    
}else{        
    otherElToShow.style.display= 'block';
}
```

Might not be the best way to do this, but I'd suggest using jQuery it makes this process a lot easier.